# How to show weekday in Windows 10 clock in taskbar?

Tags: taskbar, date-time, clock, windows-10

In all windowses before 10 I could just pull the taskbar up and I could see which day it is:

[image]

But when doing that in Windows 10 it doesn't work:

[image]

How can I get my weekday back without having to hover over the clock?

Comment: You probably can't, not without a third-party app. I'm not sure how a single-click to the clock is more arduous than pulling up the taskbar; same number of clicks.

Comment: I keep the taskbar always this way :) Probably should've mentioned that, I mean I pull up the taskbar after each windows install :P

Comment: Which version or build of Windows 10 is it? For some reason, I see the weekday on my clock. What if you pull the taskbar a little higher?

Comment: oh, when I pull it 3x small icon high it's there, but 3x small or 2x normal is too big :(

Comment: I use Penteract Clock (from the Windows Store) for this. Unfortunately it's not free :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock for this, it provides many other options beside custom formats for the clock

Comment: Yeah I'm using this, I guess this is the only real left option?

Answer (score 24):

The weekday will be shown on your horizontal taskbar when you either

- Have *Small Taskbar Icons* enabled and the Taskbar is at least *3 rows high* or
- Have *Small Taskbar Icons* disabled and the Tasbar is at least *2 rows high*

If you use the vertical taskbar

- You need to have it at least *80 pixels wide @ 100% scaling*

If you can't pull on your taskbar to resize it right-click it and uncheck *Lock all taskbars*

Comment: This is the best option as it allows the Day to show without either installing third-party software or altering system-wide time format settings

Answer (score 14):

- Go to: Control panel -> Clock and region -> Region
- in Region 'Format' tab go to 'Additional settings'
- in the date format box you can change short date. My format is : M/dd-ddd

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution if you don't want to have an unusually wide taskbar. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Go to taskbar properties & UN-check "Use small taskbar button". When you use the small taskbar buttons there is not enough room for the date unless you increase the taskbar size.

Answer (score 4):

If you unlock the taskbar and make it a little bigger, it will show the day:

[image: Taller Taskbar]

To unlock the taskbar: click Start then the settings icon, go to Taskbar Settings:

[image]

And turn "Lock the Taskbar" off:

[image]

Comment: I know it may sound obvious to you, but for some users unlocking taskbar is not really straightforward. Do you mind just adding a quick guide on how would you go about unlocking the taskbar and moving taskbar to the right side? Add this info to your answer.

Comment: @alljamin Sure. I added it. I deleted the part about moving the Taskbar to the side because it wasn't related, and it would just confuse the issue. But for reference: Once the Taskbar is unlocked, you can just grab the background of the taskbar with the mouse and drag it to any desktop edge, and it will stick there.

Comment: I really only want it to use 2 lines and to not include the day of the week. How do I do that? My short date is M/d/yyyy and my long date is MMMM d, yyyy. I can't seem to get rid of the day of the week. And I really want to use small icons. So right now I have just the time, but expanding it shows the same as the 3 line example that you showed.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the date format of the short date  in control panel -> change date, time, or number formats -> additional settings -> date. Set it to something like `ddd d-M-yy` will give you what you want

Comment: I read this trick and it will "damage" other programs that rely on this date, like excel or word. eg insert time now will insert the current day too.

Comment: True. If you use that feature it would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This fix works, but does screw up usage of the short date format in other programs, such as Outlook, Word, Excel etc. These negative effects, however, are reduced (maybe even eliminated) if you put the "ddd" insert at the END of the short date format. I'm using "M/d/yyyy - ddd" and it doesn't seem to carryover into the other programs in the same way as when I put the "ddd" string at the beginning.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your method in action?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot of me using the d/M/yy ddd setup and turning off small icons.

Screenshot showing control panel settings for date and time, and the taskbar showing the date and day

[image]

Comment: Please add a text answer explaining what's in the image (I can't actually read the text here).

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you just want to show the date of the month on the screen somewhere yet keep your taskbar slim and you use Google Calendar a lot, may I suggest you just keep a tab to Google Calendar open. That tab shows the day of the month.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the format of the date in the control panel...
With the Task bar set to double height>
Control Panel>Clock, Language, and Region> Region>Change date, time or number formats....
Select Additional Settings
Select Date Tag
in short date in "Date Formats" change it to dddd MMM dd, yyyy (Type it in Manually as it is not a selection choice)
Select apply then ok this will close the Additional Setting window
Select apply then ok this will close the Region Window

Now you should see something like Monday Nov 30, 2015 on the bottom line with the Time above it.

That's about the only way to do this without any additional third party apps

This can change the format across the board in all your apps like Excel/Word and alike when you want to insert the date, it will insert the day as well.  If this is not a problem then go ahead and use the steps, if not you will have to put up with no day being displayed... Entirely up to you

Comment: [This just duplicates an already existing answer.](http://superuser.com/questions/947237/how-to-show-weekday-in-windows-10-clock-in-taskbar/949653#9496530)

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the time.  Adjust date/time. Change date and time formats. The short date format needs to be MM/dd/yy.

Comment: That format does not include the weekday (and also uses the US order of month and day, which the OP is clearly not using)