# Windows 10 doesn't show date

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, date

[image]

My PC with Windows 10 doesn't show the date - refer to the picture. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the task bar, select Properties. Uncheck "Use small taskbar buttons". That will make your task bar big enough to fit the date.

Comment: Keep "Use small task bar buttons" checked , and stretch the taskbar to height (if horizontal) or width (if vertical) to accommodate the date and day of week to show

Comment: If you want to keep using small task bar buttons but still get both the time and date, see this answer:  https://superuser.com/questions/950196/show-the-date-on-the-system-tray-in-windows-10/1731533#1731533