# How to add the date in the taskbar clock without having to resize it?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, date-time, date, clock

I don't have much icons so I'd like to keep the taskbar minimal to save more screen space. However I'd like to have the date visible. How can I do that in Windows 7?

For example, `15:31` should be `15:31 Tue 6`:

[image]

Comment: An outside software solution was found in [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/950196/show-the-date-on-the-system-tray-in-windows-10). See here: https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [White-Tiger/T-Clock: Highly configurable Windows taskbar clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock)

This software is so cool. I wish I've found it earlier.

[image]
[image]